# Can I omit the following words in order to make sentence shorter or concise?

Tags: grammar, sentence, omissibility, concision

> A is a literary word but B **is** casual and everyday **word**.

Comment: You need the _is_, and you need _a_ before _word_, but not if you're gonna leave out _word_.

Comment: You need *a* before *casual*.

Comment: **Casual** and **everyday** are not both needed. If you want shorter, look there.

Comment: Now I got it. You want to remove **is** and **word**. Yes, you can: A is a literary word, but B, casual. Note the comma that signals the gap.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't expect users to read your mind. I'm glad @YosefBaskin got it and commented because when I first saw the question this morning I was totally flummoxed. “What words? I just see a sentence.” On EL&U questions need to show a bit more effort.

Comment: It's getting quite tiresome to spend time on an answer only to have the question closed.  Is it really more important to close questions than not to alienate contributors? Couldn't the question be bumped to ELL? Not sure what kind of "research" you'd expect the questioner to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A is a literary word but **B** is casual and everyday **word**.

You can omit **word**.

> A is a literary word but B is casual and everyday.

Note that "everyday" is being used there in a somewhat casual manner. It isn't usually deployed as a predicate adjective after the copula. You could surround it in quotation marks:

> A is a literary word but B is casual and "everyday".

Or you could  omit **word** twice and put the words in question inside quotation marks:

> "A" is literary but "B" is casual.

Or you could omit the first instance of **word** and repeat the article:

> "A" is a literary but "B" is a casual word.

And you could omit the first **word** and the second **is**:

> "A" is a literary but "B" a casual word.

That last version is itself a tad literary in style.

Answer (score -1):

According to hints, the following two sentences are not correct then. [Post updated]

> A is a literary word but B is a casual and everyday.
>
> A is a literary word, but B, casual and everyday.

Comment: "a casual and everyday" isn't idiomatic.

Comment: According to Yosef Baskin and Peter Shor, but you misunderstood what PS was saying, `You need a before casual` he meant the example sentence should have "**a** *casual* **word**" and you should read Baskin's suggestion more carefully, he explained: `A is a literary word, but B, casual. ` which is perfectly grammatical. Your examples are not.